# gadget in site with custom setting fields

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm wondering if the following is possible.

When you insert your gadget in a site page, you can config some settings such as height, border and url.

Is it possible to add custom fields to config the gadget?

For example, use selects the gadget (url), then additional fields appear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

There's workarounds to achieve such functionality (i.e. have a set of parameters for a script per sites page), but it's not possible to do specifically what you're asking. i.e. to put a parameter field on the script gadget interface.

Anyway, that seems like a real good enhancement Apps Script gadgets for Sites could have. You could open an enhancement request on Apps Script [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: So you have placed the parameters in the content of the site page. For example as hidden comment or attachment. How does your gadget know in which site page it is running?

Comment: Please star, enhancement request: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1982

Comment: You can call `SitesApp.getActivePage()` to know which page you're in.